# I need to press the power button a few times to turn on my PC

Tags: hardware-failure

My PC is 3 years old. It is running Windows 7 normally but I need to press the power on button at least twice before the PC can turn on.

Does it mean that my PC's motherboard has some problem?
Or is it caused by the PSU?

Thank you

Comment: do not have my crystall-ball with me. Could be that on pin is lose on the motherboard (MB) for the switch connection. But could be also a series defect of the MB.

Comment: Could even be a dead or weak clock battery.